# How to perform a search for a string inside math environments in a tex/latex document

Tags: latex, auctex, search, isearch-filter-predicate

I have a long tex document and I would like to perform a search for finding some string inside math environments. Is there a search function already provided by `auctex` to do this? Other solutions are welcomed.

(I found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19845598/emacs-regex-replacing-a-string-inside-a-latex-equation on a similar topic for replacing a string inside math environments).

Comment: I'm not sure I understood the question, and probably "forward search" in the context of LaTeX means something different from what you mean. Do you want to search for a particular string and want to be sure it is inside math mode?

Comment: I edited the question, 'forward search' may be confused with inverse/forward search between output and tex source. I just mean an ordinary search as you wrote.

Comment: I'd have suggested to use `texmathp` (to test whether the string is inside math mode) together with standard Emacs searching facilities, but this possibility is already mentioned in the question on stackoverflow you linked. What's wrong with it?

Comment: I thought since I am interested to perform only a search (and not find-replace as in the link), there exists perhaps an easier way to do it. Anyway I am happy with the solution given in the link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bundled with AUCTeX there is the `texmathp` utility (which, however, is independent from the TeX modes provided by AUCTeX and can be used without it), which allows you to test whether point is inside a mathematical mode or not.

The simplest suggestion I can give you is to combine `texmathp` with `search-forward`, here is a possible implementation:

```lisp
(defun mg-search-in-math (string)
  (interactive "MSearch string: ")
  (while (null (and (search-forward string)
            (texmathp)))))
```

Comment: Great. Is there an easy way to do this with incremental search (isearch)?

Comment: Not sure, but maybe this is worth a new question on its own?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I agree---I created a new question here: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/56102/how-to-perform-incremental-search-inside-math-environments-in-tex-latex-document