# How to perform query-replace inside mathematical expressions in latex

Tags: latex, auctex, query-replace, isearch-filter-predicate

Inspired by this [answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/27387), I have written the following function to perform a query-replace inside a math environment, but it does not work.

**Edit**. If you execute the function, the query-search tries to find all occurrences of `string1`, not necessarily those in math expressions, in other words `texmathp` is ignored.

Any hint to correct the code is welcomed.

```
(defun my-query-replace-in-math (string1 string2)
  (interactive "Mfrom-string: \nMto-string: ")
  (while (and (query-replace string1 string2) (texmathp))))
```

Comment: What does "it does not work" mean?  Elaborate.  Show us details.

Comment: @phils some explanations were added.

Comment: Use `isearch-filter-predicate` to ignore matches that don't satisfy `texmathp`. See the doc for that variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by @Drew, this can be achieved by setting `isearch-filter-predicate` appropriately.  Indeed, the docstring for `query-replace` includes:

`C-h f query-replace`

> ...
>
> Ignore read-only matches if ‘query-replace-skip-read-only’ is non-nil,
>   ignore hidden matches if ‘search-invisible’ is nil, and ignore more
>   matches using ‘isearch-filter-predicate’.

Here's a proposal allowing to toggle between "normal" and "math only" query replace:

```el
(defun isearch-filter-visible-and-texmath (beg end)
  "Possible value for isearch-filter-predicate."
  (and (isearch-filter-visible beg end)
       (save-excursion (goto-char beg) (texmathp))))

(defun toggle-query-replace-in-maths ()
  "Toggle restricting query-replace to TeX math content."
  (interactive)
  (setq-local isearch-filter-predicate
              (if (eq isearch-filter-predicate #'isearch-filter-visible)
                  (progn
                    (message "Query replace now only in math")
                    #'isearch-filter-visible-and-texmath)
                (progn
                  (message "Query replace back to normal")
                  #'isearch-filter-visible))))
```

Note that `setq-local` is used so that the change is buffer local (it probably does not make sense for non tex buffers, anyway).

I don't find it totally satisfactory, since it will break other changes that could have been done to `isearch-filter-predicate`.  Maybe someone will propose something better!

Comment: Thank you for devoting time to provide this answer. I may have some comments after testing.

Comment: It is interesting that, when `toggle-query-replace-in-maths` in enabled, one can also do an `isearch-forward` (C-s) in math. The only inconvenience is that, when something is found, the entire equation from its beginning until the found term is highlighted. To see what I mean do a C-s for `n` in `$A_{n}(X_1,\ldots,X_n)=0$`, then press C-s again.

Comment: @Name `isearch-forward` being affected is not unexpected, given the name of the variable, but the highliting is indeed annoying.  This needs more investigation!

Comment: I've been struggling with this problem for a long time and I was very happy to find this very elegant solution!  Thank you very much!!  However I found a litthe glitch, probably  within `texmathp`, which prevents proper behavior when replacing within a construct I often use in TeX, namely `$$ long equation $$$$ long equation continued $$`.  The second math environment is not recognized as such, unless I use a space between the 4.th and 5.th dollar sign.

Comment: I proposed a new answer that shoul solve some of the issues highlighted in these comments.

Answer (score 0):

Here: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/80544/15606, I have proposed a solution that should also adapt to this case.

This should address some of the issues highlighted in the comments to JeanPierre's answer, including JeanPierre's own doubts about the potential loss of configuration of `isearch-filter-predicate`. By using let-binding to temporarily set the value of `isearch-filter-predicate`, the issue of highlighting in `isearch-forward` should be resolved using `save-match-data` in the predicates.

Moreover, the documentation of `isearch-filter-predicate` states:

> Predicate to filter hits of Isearch and replace commands. Isearch hits
> that don’t satisfy the predicate will be skipped. The value should be
> a function of two arguments; it will be called with the positions of
> the start and the end of the text matched by Isearch and replace
> commands.  If this function returns nil, Isearch and replace commands
> will continue searching without stopping at resp. replacing this
> match. **This function is expected to be careful not to clobber the
> match data**.