# How to perform incremental search inside math environments in tex/latex documents

Tags: latex, auctex, isearch, isearch-filter-predicate

Is there a way to perform **incremental** search that filters out all non-math environments (i.e., only searches within `$...$,` `$$...$$`, and if possible other relevant `\begin{..}..\end{..}` environments)?

Note: a [similar question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/27378/how-to-perform-a-search-for-a-string-inside-math-environments-in-a-tex-latex-doc) provided an answer without the incremental part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works.

```
(defun latex-isearch-in-math ()
  "Call `isearch-forward' with `isearch-filter-predicate' set to filter out matches outside LaTeX math environments."
  (interactive)
  (let ((isearch-filter-predicate
         (lambda (BEG END)
           (save-excursion (save-match-data (goto-char BEG) (texmathp)))))
        (case-fold-search nil))
    (funcall 'isearch-forward)))
```

Note: it is almost identical to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65295/editor-that-replaces-only-text-inside-math-environments), except `call-interactively` must be replaced with `funcall`.

Answer (score 1):

I have written a function to temporarily set the value of isearch-filter-predicate (it works with `query-replace*` functions too):

```el
;; From AUCTeX, but it works as a standalone too:
(require 'texmathp)

(defvar-local ifp-predicates-list '(skip-maths keep-maths)
  "List of isearch filter predicates")

(defun skip-maths (beg end)
  "Return nil if some text BEG to END is in a LaTeX maths
environment or in in-line maths."
  (catch 'skip-region
    (let ((pos beg))
      (save-excursion
        (save-match-data
          (goto-char pos)
          (while (< pos end)
            (when (texmathp) (throw 'skip-region nil))
            (goto-char (setq pos (1+ pos)))))
        t))))

(defun keep-maths (beg end)
  "Return t if some text BEG to END is NOT in a LaTeX maths
environment or in in-line maths."
  (catch 'skip-region
    (let ((pos beg))
      (save-excursion
        (save-match-data
          (goto-char pos)
          (while (< pos end)
            (unless (texmathp) (throw 'skip-region nil))
            (goto-char (setq pos (1+ pos)))))
        t))))
```

```el
(defun with-temp-isearch-filter-predicate-test ()
  "Temporarily assigns a predicate to the variable `isearch-filter-predicate`
in order to make portions of the buffer visible/invisible to search and replacement functions
based on specific criteria."
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (let* ((IFP_DEFAULT isearch-filter-predicate)
           ;; https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/80307/15606 :
           (set-message-function nil)
           (IFP (completing-read
                 "Specify which predicate you want to activate [TAB]: "
                 ifp-predicates-list
                 nil
                 t
                 nil
                 nil
                 nil))
           (isearch-filter-predicate (intern-soft IFP))
           ;; Non-nil means to allow minibuffer commands while in the minibuffer:
           (enable-recursive-minibuffers t))
      (read-string
       (format
        "The current value assigned to the variable `isearch-filter-predicate' is `%s'.
Press ENTER to restore the default value (`%s') at the end of the operations: "
        IFP
        IFP_DEFAULT)))))
```

[image]

I'm working on a function to combine "multiple" predicates at the same time.