# Emacs 29.1: read-string prompt and other messages in minibuffer

Tags: prompt, read-string

I recently upgraded to `Emacs 29.1` from `Emacs 26.3`.

I primarily use `Emacs` as a `LaTeX` document editor. One of the things I do is use loops to select and isolate regions in the buffer for operations. In these loops, I use the `read-string` function to control the transition from one iteration to the next.

This is an example:

```el
(defun my-function ()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (let ((enable-recursive-minibuffers t))
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (while (search-forward-regexp "\\\\bibitem" nil t)
    (save-excursion
      (let* ((b (copy-marker (match-beginning 0)))
         (e (copy-marker (progn 
                   (search-forward-regexp 
                    "\\(?:\\\\bibitem\\|\\\\end{thebibliography}\\)" nil t)
                   (match-beginning 0)))))

        (save-restriction
          (narrow-to-region b e)
          (read-string 
           "Make any further manual corrections if necessary and press [ENTER]: "))))))))

(defun it-to-emph ()
  (interactive)
  (query-replace "{\\it " "\\emph{" nil (point-min) (point-max)))
```

And this is a `LaTeX` code snippet:

```latex
\begin{thebibliography}{99}

\bibitem{Bombelli:1986rw}
L.~Bombelli, R.K.~Koul, J.~Lee and R.D.~Sorkin,
\emph{A Quantum Source of Entropy for Black Holes},
\href{https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.34.373}{\emph{Phys. Rev. D} {\bfseries 34} (1986) 373}.


\bibitem{Srednicki:1993im}
M.~Srednicki,
{\it Entropy and area},
\href{https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.71.666}{\emph{Phys. Rev. Lett.} {\bfseries 71} (1993) 666}
[\href{https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9303048}{{\ttfamily hep-th/9303048}}].


\bibitem{Holzhey:1994we}
C.~Holzhey, F.~Larsen and F.~Wilczek,
{\it Geometric and renormalized entropy in conformal field theory},
\href{https://doi.org/10.1016/0550-3213(94)90402-2}{\emph{Nucl. Phys. B} {\bfseries 424} (1994) 443}
[\href{https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9403108}{{\ttfamily hep-th/9403108}}].

\end{thebibliography}
```

I have noticed that in previous versions of Emacs, any messages temporarily overlaid the read-string prompt in the minibuffer.

**Emacs 26.3** (Look at the "Replaced 1 occurrence" message)
[image]

However, in `Emacs 29.1`, messages are displayed alongside the `read-string` prompt.

**Emacs 29.1** (Look at the "Replaced 1 occurrence" message)

[image]

1. Is there a way to restore the behavior of previous versions?
2. Is `read-string` the wrong function to be used for this purpose?

**Note.** The same thing happens with the prompt of `query-replace`.

Comment: I think this is deliberate, but I can't find the change responsible at the moment. Look into `set-message-functions`, maybe one of the functions there does what you want.

Comment: There was a long discussion during 27.1 pretest which is related, but one comment in the thread (by @Drew) might be more closely relevant here, in view of the OP's second question: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gnu-emacs/2019-12/msg00460.html. But the whole thread is worth reading, just to get a feel for all the complications. Also, it's probably not the last word: given the disagreements that surfaced then, it's probably the case that more discussion and more work was done in this area during subsequent release cycles.

Comment: @rpluim let-binding the `set-message-function` variable to `nil` restores the previous behaviuor. But it's not clear to me why. Do you think I can consider it a solution? If you'd like, please post your comment as an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: `set-message-function` or `set-message-functions`? The latter could be considered part of the contract, and the former is an implementation detail, so things might break in later releases (unless Emacs adds a specific function for `set-message-functions` that means "restore emacs-26 behaviour").

Comment: Actually, I take that back: `set-message-function` is just as much part of the contract, and the `nil` behaviour is documented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

emacs-27 introduced `set-message-function` to call `set-message-functions`, which by default appends the message to the prompt. To get back the emacs-26 behaviour, set or let-bind `set-message-function` to `nil`.